# Cannot push and output the vector

Tags: c++, vector, primes

Try to store prime numbers and output them but the console is empty and nothing happens

[image]

```
int main() {
    vector <int> v;
    int n = 1000;
    
    int order; // Nth order
    //cin >> order;
    primes(n, v);
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: Nothing happens because the vector v is empty in main. You pass it by value to the function primes which makes a copy and operates on the copy and not the original. Use pass by reference instead.

Answer (score 5):

You vector argument to the function is passed by value (copied).  And so changes to it are not visible outside the function.  Try passing it by reference.

Comment: An example of how to pass by reference  would help complete this answer.